# Set checkbox state in listview Adapter

Tags: android

I have a few checkboxes that are selected when a user builds a car.  Then in my listview adapter i'm trying to account for this.  Below is my code, I don't think "setText" will work for a checkbox.

This is my error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4122)
```

Here is my listview adapter code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(v == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_car, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtMake = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_make);
        holder.txtModel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_model);
        holder.c1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.c1);
        holder.c2 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.c2);



        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    // fill row data
    Car currentItem = getItem(position);
    if(currentItem != null) {
        holder.txtMake.setText(currentItem.getMake());
        holder.txtModel.setText(currentItem.getModel());
        holder.c1.setText(currentItem.getc1());  //<--error here
        holder.c2.setText(currentItem.getc2());  //<--error here
    }

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in Log:

> Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Probably `getc1()` and `getc2()` methods returning `int` type value so system considering both values as ids and trying to find in values resources.

Use `String.valueOf` method to show `int` value as text in `CheckBox`:

```
    holder.txtMake.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getMake()));
    holder.txtModel.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getModel()));
    holder.c1.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getc1()));  
    holder.c2.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getc2()));
```